# C++ Convert Hex Char to Bin

Tags: c++, binary, hex, converters

i coded a program for convert 16 char of hexadecimal number to 64-bit binary. 64 = 16 hex + 4 digit bin.

```
string completeBitmap;
char bitmap[16];
for (int c = 0; c < sizeof(bitmap); c++)
{
    string temp;
    temp = bitset<4>(bitmap[c]).to_string();
    completeBitmap += temp;
}
```

but when i read **'a', 'b, 'c', 'd', 'e'**, and **'f'**, they dont convert correctly.
for example, **'f'** should be **'1111'** but resulting **'0110'**.
thanks for help

Comment: Character `'f'` happens to have an ASCII code of `0x66`. `0110 == 0x6` - the least significant four bits of that ASCII code. Which part of documentation suggested to you that `bitset<4>('f')` would result in a bitset of `1111`?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++){
    bitset<sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT> binary(c); //sizeof() returns bytes, not bits!
    cout << "Letter: " << c << "\t";
    cout << "Hex: " << hex << (int)c << "\t";
    cout << "Binary: " << binary << endl;
}
```

Check this.

Answer (score 0):

`bitset<4>(bitmap[c]).to_string();` will give you binary (last 4 LSB) for ascii code of elements in `bitmap` array

You probably need something like following:

```
for (int c = 0; bitmap[c] ; c++)
{
    string temp;
    char diff = 0 ;

    if( bitmap[c] >= 'a' && bitmap[c] <= 'f' ) diff = -'a' + 10;

    else if( bitmap[c] >= 'A' && bitmap[c] <= 'F' ) diff = -'A' + 10 ;

    else if (  bitmap[c] >= '0' && bitmap[c] <= '9' ) diff = - '0' ;

    else assert ( false );

    temp = bitset<4>(bitmap[c] + diff ).to_string();

    completeBitmap += temp  ;
}
```